# Django 1.6 : MySQL ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, mysql-connector

According to the django tutorial on its official website, django creates database schema according to the model defined in the `models.py`. But the default engine for database is `sqlite3`. And it is working.

now when I installed the `mysql` and `Mysql Connector` for django and I tried to create a database I encountered with the following error:

```
 mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'db.mysql.userdb'
```

I searched the error and found some solutions to this problem but all of them mentioned that I have to create the database myself using `MYSQL Shell`. But this is not what I want! According to the django website, I have to just define my model and django creates the schema of database! *How can I do that?*

Thanks in advance.

The following is my `sttings.py` file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))      

SECRET_KEY = '94sf3cp(#a^)9!^zrr^zr3dfdk0nz$*4=m#v19*v)j&q^o$#ym'

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'website_user',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Final_DBMI.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Final_DBMI.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'db.mysql.userdb',
        'USER': 'hadi',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True       

STATIC_URL = '/statics/'
```

**Update**
I'm using this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/) and according to that there is two ways to connect to mysql:

- MYSQLdb
- MySQL Connector/Python

and I'm using the second one. According to the [MYSQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html) it should be added to `settings.py` in the following way:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django creates the *tables*. It does not create the *database* that the tables live in; you must do that.

Answer (score 0):

db settings like this,

install the mysql-python in your environment using pip

```
pip install mysql-python
```

create the database(userdb) in your mysql using below command,

```
create database userdb;
```

then your settings.py file follow these settings,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'userdb',
        'USER': 'mysql username',
        'PASSWORD': 'mysql password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Here is reference link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

Comment: It gives me this: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb`, I'm not using `MySQLdb`. I use this [one](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python). and it says to add it in [this way](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html)